# How to find path with maximum cost

Tags: java, graph-algorithm

I have a directed graph whose vertices have costs. I would like to find the path with maximum cost between two vertices, but I have only found algorithms to solve the path with minimum cost.

Also, I'm using Java.

Comment: does your graph have negative edge weights? or edge weights with zero cost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Normalize all costs so that the minimum cost is greater than 0.
2. Change all costs to (1/cost).
3. Run minimum cost algorithm.

The resulting path is the maximum cost path on the original graph.

Comment: this should work if the none of the edge costs are negative or 0

Comment: @user396089 that's what step 1. is for

Comment: That will add O(n) complexity for normalizing the costs. Algorithm modification(if possible) will be more efficient.

Comment: Linear complexity is cheap.  Why bother?

Comment: I think this is not correct. Consider a graph with nodes A, B, C, D and the following edges and edge costs: A->D (1), A->B (2), B->C (2), C->D (2). Let's say we're looking for the path from nodes A->D; there are two options for it: A->D with cost 1 or A->B->C->D with maximum cost 6. Your algorithm would still output A->D as its result (because 1/1=1) instead of A->B->C->D (because 1/2+1/2+1/2=1.5).

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the evaluation function of the algorithm used. If for the shortest path, the function returns a greater value for shorter paths, in your case you would want to return a smaller value for shorter paths.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [Longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), which (assuming you are looking for *simple* paths, i.e. paths in which no node is visited multiple times) is NP-hard, meaning that no algorithm that computes it in polynomial time exists unless P=NP. The proof for that is related to the [Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem), which is also NP-hard. Looking for paths that are not simple doesn't make much sense, because you could just keep looping through a cycle with positive cost, resulting in infinite total cost.

If you're sad about this fact, listen to [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210427235848/https://sarielhp.org/misc/funny/#longest-path).

Yet, you have a directed acyclic graph (DAG), there is a method using topological sorting, which is explained in the linked Wikipedia article. This problem has to do with the [Critical path method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_path_method) used for scheduling a set of project activities.